# Are the ckpt data under Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 compatible?

Tags: tensorflow

My model is written with Python, and I got ckpt data under Python 2.7 and Python 3.4, Are they(ckpt data) compatible? Since Python 2.7 is not compatible with Python 3.x

It will cost a lot time to train the model to get the ckpt data, so didn't try with both ckpt data under Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 to test whether they(ckpt data) are compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkpoints are stored using [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) ([`Saver` source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py)), and therefore its format is independent of the Python version. In fact, in theory you could even load checkpoint files in C++, for example.

Checkpoint compatibility could break if the Protocol Buffers specs for TensorFlow models change after a release, but that seems rather unlikely.